# Angular Material Sliding Tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to create sliding tabs with angular material tabs. I could do this by using `$interval` and change the index. I'm not sure that is right way. 
Any help about the right way would be appreciated.

Edit: [An Example](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/)

Comment: what do you mean by `sliding tabs`? could you provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, to do it with `$interval` is most suitable approach.

Autoplay for `md-tabs` [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZYbNb?editors=1010).

Comment: How could we use different tabsAutoplayDelay in your example? Thanks

Comment: @TheNone I wrote `tabsAutoplay`directive which could help you to use different delay time for each `md-tabs` element. Please review here: [autoplay for `md-tabs`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZYbNb?editors=1010)